# Dual boot WINPE and WINRE USB?

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-restore

Can this be done? I think it would be cool to have one USB to access these.

Leon

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can dual boot a usb drive, not in the traditional sense anyway. But you can definitely use something like UBCD as a boot manager. Not only does it have a lot of useful diagnostic tools built in, but you can [customize the menu](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/customize.html) to add whatever images you want. You can also modify it to work in a [USB stick](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/install-and-boot-ultimate-boot-cd-ubcd-from-a-usb-device/).